# Auto-takeoff status when using OnBoard SDK with A3

Tags: dji-sdk

I have the following setup:
A3 with the latest firmware (1.7.0)
DJI Assistant 2 (1.1.0) for simulating flights
Linux Machine to run the app which uses OnBoard SDK

What I am doing is trying to make the flight:
Auto Takeoff --> Set Waypoints --> [Flight by the simulator] --> Land

The problem is that when I switch to Auto-Takeoff, I don't know when the take off has finished. This is the problem because if I upload the Waypoint Setting and Data too early, it simply does nothing and no error is returned.

I checked that the example from github implement "monitoredTakeoff" function which calculates the takeoff state by itself, based on velocity - but this is less preferable way for me.

Am I missing something? Is there a way the drone can notify that it has finished taking off?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As on Jan 2018, you can subscribe to [DisplayMode](https://developer.dji.com/onboard-api-reference/namespaceDJI_1_1OSDK_1_1VehicleStatus_1_1DisplayMode.html) telemetry , and monitor its value - it will change from MODE_AUTO_TAKEOFF to MODE_P_GPS after the takeoff is successful.